# jQuery not appending title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On my page I want the user to be able to `mouseover` a `td` element, have the page make an Ajax call to the server, and then append a `title` attribute to the `td` to serve as a tooltip for the remainder of the time the user is on the page.

The information the page needs to retrieve is very basic so there's nothing too complicated about this... however I cannot get the code to append the `data` I receive from the Ajax call onto the `td` element.

**Jquery/Ajax**

```
$('.ChannelCodeDesc').mouseover(function () {

    //Only append if we don't have a title
    if (!$(this).attr('title')) {

        //Let me know when we're about to make Ajax call
        console.log('ajax');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDesc", "ZipCodeTerritory")',
            data: { channel: $.trim($(this).text()) },
            success: function (data) {

                //Append to td
                $(this).attr('title', data);

                //Display what we got back
                console.log(data);
            }
        });                
    }

    //What does the title look like when we're done?
    console.log($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Unfortunately I can see, in the console, the `'ajax'` entry, followed by the exact value I'm expecting for the `data` object, but `undefined` appears as the value for the `td` `title` attribute from the final `console.log` statement (end of the `mouseover`).

**HTML/Razor**

```
<td class="ChannelCodeDesc">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.displayForPaging[i].ChannelCode)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.displayForPaging[i].ChannelCode)
</td>
```

**Ajax Controller Method**

```
    public JsonResult GetDesc(string channel)
    {
        var description = (from c in db.Channel
                           where c.ChannelCode.Equals(channel)
                           select c.ChannelLongDescription).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(description, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste the exact JSON response that returned ?

Comment: what does the console show if you use `console.log($(this).attr('title'))` inside the `success` cb? are you sure the reference `$(this)` is working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` object in the success function is not the td element. By default the context of the jquery ajax callbacks is set as an object representing the ajax options. However you can change that using the [context option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$('.ChannelCodeDesc').mouseover(function () {

    //Only append if we don't have a title
    if (!$(this).attr('title')) {

        //Let me know when we're about to make Ajax call
        console.log('ajax');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDesc", "ZipCodeTerritory")',
            data: { channel: $.trim($(this).text()) },
            context: this, //make sure "this" inside the success callback is the td element
            success: function (data) {

                //Append to td
                $(this).attr('title', data);

                //Display what we got back
                console.log(data);
            }
        });                
    }

    //What does the title look like when we're done?
    console.log($(this).attr('title')); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The final console.log statement shows undefined because it occurs before the AJAX request is complete (because AJAX requests are Asynchronous).

Also, a td can't have a title attribute, might need to look at a different option:
[how to apply style to 'title' attribute of 'td' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515490/how-to-apply-style-to-title-attribute-of-td-tag)

And others have stated, can't use $this inside the ajax success function like that.

Comment: This isn't an answer why his code doesn't work. It just answer why the last line is `undefined`.

Comment: He doesnt say the code doesnt work, just that the value in the log is undefined.

Comment: The title say it all `jQuery not appending title`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the data returned by Ajax is valid.... 
the $(this) within success does not refer to the td anymore.

do this outside the ajax call:

```
var me = $(this);
```

Then in your success code do this:

```
me.attr('title', data);
```