# change color of Select Tag Title

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code

CSS

```
select.select { 
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    height: 15px; 
    width: 105px; 
    background:#996633
}
```

HTML

```
<select class="select" title="Select A Value">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

In the following code I am able to change the font color of `select` box but I don't know how to change the color of `title` in `<select>` Tag. Can any one help me with this?

The reference I got from 
http://cssglobe.com/post/8802/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements

The above site

Comment: not sure if it's a typo but you *had* before the edits selcect instead of select.  Check your code too

Comment: No no my code is fine I think I accidently typed selcet instead of select

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js & dups

Comment: I think you have used javascript or Jquery. Did you? If yes then why didn't you tag jquery or Javascript.

Comment: Yes Jhilom You are right. I used Jquery for stylish Dropdown. I forgot to put the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing. I have cheked the site you provided. You may find `span.select` on the CSS. just add

your required color there

for example

```
span.select 
{ 
//Other Codes
color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

I think your problem will be solved..

It was not CSS or HTML Problem. The Title Tag is coming from jquery. Thanks for giving the link. Your JSFiddle example doesn't show your actual query as you did not provide all of the information there

Comment: Don't mix up Jquery or HTML problem together or you may never rich to your proper destination

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple customized select box - http://code.google.com/p/select-box/

Comment: @user1379021 Check the links I have posted

Comment: That styles an element with a title attribute, it doesn't style the title attribute.

Comment: I am not wanting Tooltip. I just want The Select Tag Title to change its color.

Comment: @user1379021 — The title attribute (which isn't a tag) is very rarely rendered as anything other than a tooltip.

Comment: http://cssglobe.com/post/8802/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements

Check this. And I think you will get the code. I have downloaded that from here