# Styling HTML Title attribute using CSS

Tags: html, css, title

I am trying to style the title attribute of a `<input type="text">` using CSS. So this is what I did:

```
input[type="text"][title] {
    font-style: italic;
    color: gray;
}
```

It works okay, but when I enter data into the field, the data is gray and italic. I want the data (value) to be normal and black, and only the title to be italic and gray.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't change the style of the `title` attribute as this is handled by the OS.  What you have selects an `input` element that *has* a `title` attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a title? (and with CSS or js?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js)

Comment: You can use JavaScript to change the `title` property into another thing and finally, you can customize this other thing. Take a look [here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tooltips-create-your-own-tooltip-plugin/)

Comment: jQuery FTW on this one. There is no way to style a title attribute with standard CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174799/5996253) Maybe this will help you

Comment: I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174799/5996253) Maybe this will help you

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174799/5996253) will help you Try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a custom solution using CSS3.

Take a look at [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag). But might I suggest that you use a custom field like 'data-title' so the default browser behaviour doesn't interfere with your custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the input's title in `<h2></h2>` and then change the property of the title from css like below:

```
h2 {
    font-style: italic;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
input[type="text"][title]:hover:after {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" title="here is a title" />
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I made a snippet. It does nothing special in Chrome on a mac in 2020