# HTML5 Abbr Tag How To Style Title OnHover Text Message

Tags: css, html

```
<abbr title="United States of America">USA</abbr>
```

when you go on USA with your cursor it shows up a text box how we can edit that text box need CSS TAG

Comment: You cannot. If you want to do this, you have to do it with javascript (and CSS). Look at this for example : http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a title? (and with CSS or js?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to do it custom ?

**CSS3 :**

```
abbr:hover:before {
   content: attr(title);
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/NzntY/

or change your attr whatever you want...

```
<abbr data-yeah="United States of America">USA</abbr>
```

So

```
content: attr(data-yeah);
```

Comment: Solving in this way Works terrible on Mozilla and IE Browsers. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzntY/1/)

Comment: Just a concept/demo @FranciscoCarvalho :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Tooltip if you want to be able to style a text box that appears on hover. See:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/
- http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/
- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aPuf8/3/), which has the following jQuery to add the tooltip:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
    });
});
```

With these CSS classes:

```
.ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: bold 14px"Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
}
```

And remember you will need to include a reference the jQuery UI:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```