# Assign css class or id to tooltip in cakephp

Tags: css, cakephp, tooltip

I'm building a website with cakephp and I would like to style the layout of the tooltips. Is it possible to assign a class or id within

```
Form->input('type', array('title' =>'enter type'))
```

to style the tool tip or is there any workaround available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a title? (and with CSS or js?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you should use a JS plugin for that.. like the bootstrap one:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips