# Display new line in MS Charts Tooltip

Tags: firefox, mschart

I am using MS Charts in my project and things are going well. I am using this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/11/microsoft-chart-control-how-to-using-keywords.aspx) for complex Tooltip content, When i addd line break "\n" its working properly on IE but not on Firefox.

Check the following screenshots, any help will be appreciated.

**IE:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking into a similar solution but it seems many line feed characters work in IE but none in firefox. 
Here is a link to that - 
[How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

The other thing you can try is to use a widget like Yahoo tooltip -
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/tooltip.html