# How can I display the HTML "title" attribute in multiple lines in Firefox?

Tags: html, title

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

I would like to display the "title" attribute tooltip in several lines, so it looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

[I tried to do:](http://jsfiddle.net/UQWA2/)

```
<div title="Line 1\nLine 2">Secret</div>
```

but it didn't work.

Is that possible?

Comment: what is the sence? it wont be displayed in any browser since they all have single-line caption bar.

Comment: If you have so much information that it needs to word wrap, then you have too much information for a tooltip.

Comment: I have very few information. It just looks better in several lines!

Comment: @Quentin, what's the alternative, make a bunch of extra elements to show documentation on what the controls are for or how to use them? 

Comment: I found a small issue with multiline tooltips & mouseleave event which I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76498447/6908282)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip) you can just do it like this:

```
<div title="Line 1  
Line 2">Secret</div>
```

Though it is said that it doesn't work with Firefox.

Comment: This can cause browser incompatibilities and validation errors.

Comment: I just tested this in chrome (108.0.5359.125), Firefox (108.0.1), opera (94.0.4606.38), and edge (108.0.1462.54) and it does seem to work nicely.

Comment: Note that this considers indentation as well - which would be present in most of the code for readability. So it may not give desired results

Answer (score 115):

You can enter `&#10;`. In other words:

```
<div title="Line 1&#10;Line 2">Secret</div>
```

Comment: It works in Firefox 16.0.1, IE7+, Chrome. 

It does not work in FireFox 4.0.1 (at least).

Comment: works on Chrome 49 (OSX)

Comment: Tested in Firefox 53.0 and it worked

Comment: Does NOT work on Chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit, Linux (Ubuntu))

Comment: Works on Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit, Linux (Ubuntu))

Comment: Works on Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: hmmmm I'm not sure how this could work for anybody o.O "13" in decimal is a carriage return, as far as I understood the question, it should be `&#10;` or `&#x0a;` - I'll add an answer with some tests (because this particular SO page is still #1 in google :)) Edit: no, seems like I can't answer. See https://jsfiddle.net/kpion/Lrpxqgm2/ then. It should be e.g.  `<p title = "Charlize&#10;Theron"></p>`

Comment: Does NOT work on Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Offical), (64-bit, Windows 10)

Comment: Works for me on Chrome Version 80.0.3987.106 (64-bit, Windows 7)

Comment: Works on Chrome Version 91.0.4472.106 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: does not work on `Edge 114.0.1823.43 (Official build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2):

Either add new lines within the HTML content itself

```
<div title="Line 1
Line 2">Secret</div>
```

Or make your own tooltip using JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: This can cause browser incompatibilities and validation errors.

Comment: Adding your own tooltop using javascript/css is the only way to get this working completely cross browser.