# Wrapping title attribute

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Firefox does not wrap words in `a` `title` attribute:

```
<a title="longword"></a>
```

Is there a way to do word-wrapping in that case? I tried with:

```
<a title="longword" style="word-wrap:break-word;"></a>
```

but it does not work.

Chrome, instead, automatically wraps.

Comment: thats up to the web browser. have you considered writing your own tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot make Firefox deviate from its way of rendering `title` attribute values; cf. to [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

The tooltips created by using `title` attributes are of questionable usability (tiny font that cannot be easily increased by the user; disapperance after some seconds; etc.), so they are suitable (at most) for short advisory titles (mainly for links), which not cause a need for wrapping.

For longer tooltips, consider using CSS techniques. Or just put the tip into the text proper.

Comment: The tooltip I have done works fine for what I need. Thanks for the "carriage return problem" link, I didn't think about it.

Comment: Why not update the answer to simply say that &#10; works?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the only part of the [HTML5 specifications](http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#the-title-attribute) that deals with line breaks in `title` attributes states:

> If the `title` attribute's value contains `U+000A LINE FEED (LF)` characters, the content is split into multiple lines. Each `U+000A LINE FEED (LF)` character represents a line break.

So you *could* break up the `title` attribute on the server-side, although this is unlikely to be a desirable solution. Alternatively, you can try inserting [zero width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), though browser support for this may also be inconsistent.

Comment: This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE as of 2014/08! Use &#x0A; in the title attribute. Be careful, IE wraps the title tooltips on its own, so it's probably best to check there first how the wrapping is done and "emulate" it by placing linefeeds at the same spots to avoid having extra linebreaks in IE.

Answer (score 0):

@2023-05

Simply use `&#10;` as the linebreak like this.

```html
<div title="A &#10; Leaf &#10; Falls &#10; with &#10; Loneliness">
  Hover your mouse here to see the native tooltip content.
</div>
```

Here is a working demo.
https://codepen.io/shrekuu/pen/dygLKGO

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Use escaped n, example:

```
<input type="text" title="first line \n second line"></input>
```

Comment: Did you even try? edge, firefox, or chrome? None of them works. In fact, &#10; works.