# javascript/jQuery: Adding linebreak in title -- works in IE9, but not in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying the following to add a linebreak in the `title` attribute.

```
<p id="test" title="1|2">test</p>


 var lineBreak = $("<div>&#10</div>").html();

 $("#test").attr("title", $("#test").attr("title").replace("|", lineBreak));
```

The tooltip result in **IE9** is

```
1
2
```

in **IE8** the result is

```
12
```

Is there a chance to fix this for IE8?
I really need this way and no custom tooltip etc.

Try it @ jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCdb/

Comment: what simply if `lineBreak = "\n"` ? Could you try this?

Comment: this should help you, and it's working on IE8

http://stackoverflow.com/a/358929/1631348

Comment: @keith Not that line break in tooltips don't display in all browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#test").attr("title", $("#test").attr("title").replace("|", "\n"));
```

`\n` is a new line operator in plain text.