# Decrease the line spacing when using a multi-line image title tag

Tags: html, tags, title

I have created a title tag for an  statement and am using php commands and 
 to create multiple lines for the title.  Is there a way to decrease the line spacing between these lines or another way to have multiple lines in the title tag?  I need to use the SIZE and LINE-HEIGHT commands as well as others for this multi-line text.

This is what I have:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/storage/<?php echo $rows['file']; ?>" 
title="<?php echo $rows['field1'].$rows['field2']; echo "<br>";?>line 2
<?php echo "<br>"; ?>Line 3">Click Here</a>
```

I have tried a STYLE command within the  tag for the SIZE and it didn't work.
I have tried putting an   totally around the existing  and that didn't work either.

Any ideas???

Comment: Why don't you use a Javascript-based tooltip script and unset the attribute? For instance: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Comment: not sure if this is what you're going for, but: `\n` embedded in PHP code will force a new line in your code; you can try it out and look at the HTML source with `\n` being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newlines in the title text, you just put newlines in the value. See [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip) for more details about that part. Not sure if you can adjust the size/spacing of this text with CSS, though you could create custom popups w/ DIV tags and some jQuery. Then you'd have full control over how they look. Maybe use something someone already built, there's a bunch to choose from at http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 3):

The tooltips that browsers generate from `title` attributes cannot be styled in CSS, or in any other way. (The font can be changed by the user, but not the author.) Line breaks inside those values should be respected by browsers, but this cannot be counted on.

The tooltips also vanish after a few seconds. A usability nightmare really, if the text is several lines long.

The morale is that it is much better to use “CSS tooltips” based on completely different techniques. (You can also use JavaScript, but it’s not really needed.)