# Wicket - Add tooltip to every cell in PropertyColumn

Tags: java, wicket

I really need your help by a wicket-problem.

I want to add a tooltip to all the rows(by mouse hover) in a PropertyColumn. But how can I do it? I've seen solutions with an Abstractcolumn. But I have to use a PropertyColumn because i need the propertyExpression and don't need the sortProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have found the solution.

First thing, which is important to know is, that in the populateItem-Method, there has to be at least one object in it. For example a label. Because you can't add a string or a tooltip to a cell without something in it. So i had to put a label in it and added the string to that label. After that i've added a PrototipBehavior to the label:

```
 public void populateItem(final Item cellItem, final String componentId, final IModel model) {
                Long id = ((MyObject) model.getObject()).getId();
                String desc = ((MyObject) model.getObject()).getDescription();
                Label l = new Label(componentId, id + "");
                l.add(new PrototipBehaviour(desc));
                cellItem.add(l);

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to modify the `DataTable` like this:

```
add(new DefaultDataTable("wicektid", null, null, 10) {

    @Override
    protected Item newCellItem(String id, int index, IModel model) {
        Item item = super.newCellItem(id, index, model); 
        item.add(AttributeModifier.replace("title", "Your Title"));
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    protected Item newRowItem(String id, int index, IModel model) {
        Item item = super.newRowItem(id, index, model); 
        item.add(AttributeModifier.replace("title", "Your Title"));
        return item;
    }

});
```

Here you have the control if you want the tooltip on whole rows or on individual cells.

If you want to do it in certain columns you can override `populateItem` in the column like this:

```
add(new PropertyColumn<>(){

    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, String componentId, IModel<T> rowModel) {
        super.populateItem(item, componentId, rowModel); 
    }

});
```

Comment: The second solution is the preferred one for me. For clarity, you'd add a (Tooltip)Behaviour or something to the item in the populateItem-method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i've a question: You write in the second possible solution, that I should override `newCellItem`, but you override `populateItem`. I will try this solution as fast as possible. Yesterday I also tought about something like that. Many thx. I will update my question, when I've checked if it works. :)

Comment: @RobertNiestroj is it possible to make String in AttributeModifier as multiline, I tried <br> but in html it renders as &lt;br&gt; and it has no effect

Comment: @eatSleepCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip

Comment: @RobertNiestroj this link is useful but there is one problem the tool tip gets generated at runtime and I tried using character `&#13;` but it gets rendered as &amp;#13; which makes it display as &#13; same problem