# <br> not working in title tag for tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am using tooltipster plugin for tooltip. I am not able to use [in title]http://jsfiddle.net/varun30/wy3dp097/1/

I have tried &#013,&#x0A (this is only working for firefox ).
Do I need to make changes in css .In some of the threads I have seen 
in css:

```
.tooltip {
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

This is also not working in my case .Can we have some way to include 
 .
Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't render HTML from what you have, but if you go crazy and just actually press the enter key there, [it'll work](http://jsfiddle.net/3wj6uh14/3/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip

Answer (score 3):

In most browsers, you simply can't control browser tooltips much at all, and can't put HTML in them. If you need to do anything fancy in tooltips, sadly you'll need a CSS and/or JavaScript lib to do them.

However, line breaks are fairly straightforward. You were on the right track with entities, but the entities you tried are incorrect, they should be `&#13;&#10;`. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wj6uh14/4/) Or a literal newline works too: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wj6uh14/7/)

Inline example:

```html
<div title="Line 1&#13;&#10;Line2">Hover over me</div>
<div title="Line 1
            Line2">And me</div>
```

If you're doing this in JavaScript, just make sure your JavaScript string includes a newline:

```js
document.querySelector("div").title = "Line 1\nLine 2";
```

```html
<div>Hover over me</div>
```

Comment: I have data coming in title attribute dynamically .In that scenario plugin wont work?

Comment: @sinner: You just have to have a newline in your string, doesn't matter how it gets there. I've added a JavaScript example. Remember that the tooltip text isn't HTML. (We used entities in the markup because the value of an attribute in markup is written in HTML text, which can include entities; people tend to forget that about attributes.)

Comment: @sinner: What does "not working in browser" but "working fine in fiddle" mean? All of the above (snippets and fiddles) work fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: @Crowder: My tooltip plugin uses jquery also.Please see the updated version:http://jsfiddle.net/varun30/3wj6uh14/8/

Comment: @sinner: Doesn't matter whether you use jQuery or not. `.prop("title", "Line 1\nLine2")` is the jQuery-ified version of `.title = "Line 1\nLine 2"`.

Comment: @Crowder: using this property ,I am able to break the lines but tool tip is not coming in desired manner. 
.This how it should be. http://jsfiddle.net/varun30/3wj6uh14/8/ 
 This is how it becomes. http://jsfiddle.net/varun30/3wj6uh14/9/ .

Comment: @sinner: Obviously, you can't just start with `.` in `.prop("title", "Line 1\nLine 2")`. Please see the **working examples** above and extrapolate.

Comment: @Crowder:Hi ,I have tried .prop but that is not working for me somehow .As per current scenario I am getting my title as $("<div>").attr( 'title', "Workspace Identifiers are: "+ "- NAME <br>" + "- "+ $('#cr1').val().toUpperCase() + "<br>" + "- " + $('#cr2').val().toUpperCase()); When I call tooltipster $("<div>").tooltipster();. It doesnot work for me any other workaround?