# In javascript, newline character specified via input does not create a newline in alert

Tags: javascript, newline

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/Lnq5mffs/

#### `HTML` ..

```
<input type="text" id="separator" value="Doesnt\nwork" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
```

#### `javascript` ..

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('separator').value);
    alert("This\nworks");
};
```

#### Output ..

- first dialog:

[image: first dialog]

- second dialog:

[image: second dialog]

Comment: Use a textarea for multiline input.

Comment: try logging out the value returned by document.getElementById('separator').value in the console

Comment: @PiX06 this is whats logged: `"Doesnt\nwork"`

Comment: Escaping only works on a predefined set of characters within an HTML attribute, so `\n` literally prints out `\n`. You could use `&#10;` as a newline character (or an actual line break in the HTML itself), but then `<input>` doesn't allow for multilines. Use a `<textarea>` instead

Comment: It's interpreted as literate characters. If you do want to enter \n, you have to replace it in code with real carriage return e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq5mffs/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right, "\n" means "new line" only when used in a string literal. You can't expect that an avarage user will enter "\n" in an input box expecting that it'll be interpreted as a new line. When the user enters "\n" in the input box, the value property is set to "\\n".

If you really need the input box content to be interpreted as a string literal, you can use replace, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq5mffs/2/.

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('separator').value.replace('\\n', '\n'));
    alert("This\nworks");
};
```

Edit: If you want to provide your user a way to enter multi-line text, use textarea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea.