# How can I use a new-line character within a tooltip title html attribute inside a single-quoted echo in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Here's my echo:

```
echo '
    <div class="col-md-6 info" id="outerDiv">
        <div class="row">
            <strong>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.
                    $estado->dados($value[$c]->estado)->sigla.
                    ': '.
                    $cidade->dados($value[$c]->cidade)->nome.
                    fwrite("\n").$value[$c]->tel1.
                    '" id="title'.$c.'">'.$value[$c]->nome_fantasia.'</a>
            </strong>
                <div id="content'.$c.'" hidden>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Razão Social: '.$value[$c]->razao_social.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">CNPJ: '.$value[$c]->cnpj.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Endereço: '.$value[$c]->endereco.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Número: '.$value[$c]->numero.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Complemento: '.$value[$c]->complemento.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Bairro: '.$value[$c]->bairro.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Tel1: '.$value[$c]->tel1.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Tel2: '.$value[$c]->tel2.'</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    '
```

I've tried to use fwrite("\n"), but it does not work. I really wanted a new-line character inside that tooltip. Is there a cure?

Comment: Try putting an actual line break in the `title` attribute.

Comment: This is `fwrite()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: I've tried it, it does not work because it is single-quoted.

Comment: Have you tried `$cidade->dados($value[$c]->cidade)->nome."<br/>".$value[$c]->tel1`? Also `fwrite` is for output to file, use `"\n"`. Also some systems has `\r\n` as line end.

Comment: "<br/>" does not work, because it's inside an attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

Comment: @Amir it's different in that he is concatenating the HTML output with strings, so he needs to be more literal in order to format correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the entity code (`&#013;`)?

```
$estado->dados($value[$c]->estado)->sigla . ': ' . $cidade->dados($value[$c]->cidade)->nome . '&#013;' . $value[$c]->tel1 . '" id="title' . $c . '">' . $value[$c]->nome_fantasia
```

Another suggestion would be to use a [heredoc](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/3/heredoc) and some formatted breaks:

```
$anchor = <<<EOT

<a title='Tip
With
Carriage
Returns'>link</a>

EOT;
```

Then just concatenate the `$anchor` with the rest of your string.

*Another* suggestion would be to do this post-page-load with JavaScript:

```
var space = '\x0A';

element.setAttribute("title", 'Tip' + space + 'With' + space + 'Carriage' + space + 'Returns');
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with the bootstrap tooltip. It's not possible that nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the echo, close the PHP block and just let the parser output the HTML. If you have short tags enabled, you can embed PHP code inside this HTML using <?= ?>, otherwise you can use <? echo ?> instead.

I think this is a much cleaner way

```
?>

<div class="col-md-6 info" id="outerDiv">
    <div class="row">
        <strong>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$estado->dados($value[$c]->estado)->sigla?>: <?=$cidade->dados($value[$c]->cidade)->nome?>\n<?=$value[$c]->tel1?>" id="title<?=$c?>"><?=$value[$c]->nome_fantasia?></a>
        </strong>

        <div id="content<?=$c?>" hidden>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Razão Social: <?=$value[$c]->razao_social?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">CNPJ: <?=$value[$c]->cnpj?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Endereço: <?=$value[$c]->endereco?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Número: <?=$value[$c]->numero?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Complemento: <?=$value[$c]->complemento?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Bairro: <?=$value[$c]->bairro?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tel1: <?=$value[$c]->tel1?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tel2: <?=$value[$c]->tel2?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's as simple as losing the fwrite but still using double quotes..:

```
echo '
    <div class="col-md-6 info" id="outerDiv">
        <div class="row">
            <strong>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.
                    $estado->dados($value[$c]->estado)->sigla.
                    ': '.
                    $cidade->dados($value[$c]->cidade)->nome.
                    "\n".$value[$c]->tel1.
                    '" id="title'.$c.'">'.$value[$c]->nome_fantasia.'</a>
            </strong>
                <div id="content'.$c.'" hidden>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Razão Social: '.$value[$c]->razao_social.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">CNPJ: '.$value[$c]->cnpj.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Endereço: '.$value[$c]->endereco.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Número: '.$value[$c]->numero.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Complemento: '.$value[$c]->complemento.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Bairro: '.$value[$c]->bairro.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Tel1: '.$value[$c]->tel1.'</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Tel2: '.$value[$c]->tel2.'</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    '
```