# How to add line break in title attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qualtrics

Please find my code below which adds a tooltip on mouseover event to a field in my survey engine. 
What I want to achieve is add line breaks to the tooltip.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('#choice31QID405').mouseover(function() { 
$j(this).attr('title','My name is Glenn. <Add a line break>. I am a good boy'. <Add a line break>. I live in New Delhi); 
})

$j('#choice31QID405').mouseout(function() { 
$j(this).removeAttr('title'); 
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

Comment: no it is not duplicate. I am performing the action from jquery

Comment: If you go through all the solutions in that post you will find [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205056/456135) solution there. Anyway approach is same.

Answer (score 8):

On modern browsers, you can just use a line break:

```js
$("#target").attr("title", "Hello\nWorld");
```

```html
<p title="Hello
World">
This one is hardcoded in the HTML.
</p>
<p id="target">
This one is added later
</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That works fine on current (as of this writing) Chrome and Firefox, as well as IE11.

Answer (score 4):

Use entity code `&#010;` for line break.
Your code will look something like this:

`$j(this).attr('title','My name is Glenn.&#010;I am a good boy'.&#010;I live in New Delhi);`

Refer this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L9fytug8/)

Comment: Please elaborate your issue.

Comment: on the browser.. &#010; is appearing as part of tooltip.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is the value of title attribute properly wrapped inside quotes?

Comment: i tested on firefox. yes it is wrapped inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use `<Hr>` tag in HTML to set `line`

here is working example,

```js
   

 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j('#choice31QID405').mouseover(function() { 
    $j(this).attr('title','My name is Glenn. <hr />. I am a good boy <hr /> I live in New Delhi'); 
      $j('#test').html($j(this).attr('title'));
    });

    $j('#choice31QID405').mouseout(function() { 
    $j(this).removeAttr('title'); 
      $j('#test').html("");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    <body>
      <div id="choice31QID405">Mouse over here</div>
      <div id="test">Tooltip will show up here..</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: dude I cannot add ids to HTML. I am programming on survey platform. The html is generated on the fly. I cannot control it.