# Can I add HTML tag to jQuery attr()?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery `attr()` and I would like to add there HTML tag `<br />`, but on page it doesn't compile it and shows that tag as string. So is there any way to use HTML tag inside of `attr()` or what should I use instead of it?

Code is below, thanks for all advices!

```
if (Object.keys(result.lastComment).length > 0) {
    $(self).attr('data-original-title',
        result.commentCreatorName+  '<br />' +
        result.date + '<br />' +
        result.lastComment.comment
    );
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put a `br` tag inside an attribute in normal HTML?

Comment: @Mr.Alien jump to next row?

Comment: What you're doing will work just fine for adding `<br />` into the attribute `data-original-title`. What, if anything, that will mean will depend entirely on what you use `data-original-title` for, since it's not used for anything by the browser and will just store the text you put in it. If you use it as markup, `<br />` will be a line break. If not, it won't, it'll just be the characters `<`, `b`, `r`, ` `, `/`, and `>`.

Comment: @hstur No, that's where you are going wrong.

Comment: What you are using to compile the tag to HTML? Is there some observable that tracks the attribute?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so how could I make this work? I just need to have every value on single row..

Comment: @hstur May be you are looking for `.html()` here

Comment: @hstur use .html() here. Agree with Mr. Alien

Comment: .append would be usefull too

Comment: @cnexans `.append()` will make more sense, but I am just getting him started with basic method first

Comment: @hstur: Make ***what*** work? Again: What this does will depend entirely on what you use `data-original-title` for. If, for instance, at some point you use it to set the `title` attribute of an element, you don't want `<br />`, just a line break: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476334/how-to-add-line-break-in-title-attribute-using-jquery/42926132#42926132 But I have no idea whether that's what you're doing.

Comment: @hstur Perhaps you should spend more time exploring jQuery, or I would say, learning how to manipulate DOM. Checkout some methods like `.html()`, `.prepend()`, `.append()` and so on..

Comment: hstur . you need to share the whole `story` behind your code. Then we can answer directly on the problem. for now we can just assume what you are trying to do

Comment: @MihaiT sorry for that, but I need exactly what @T.J.Crowder said - line break where `<br />` is

Comment: for what purpose ? what do you want to use `data-original-title` for ? it all depends on what are you trying to accomplish . if you will use, for example,  `data-original-title` as `html()` then yes, the `<br />` will work. but i repeat. it all depends on what you want to do with that attribute

Comment: @MihaiT So there is a table with comment icon in the last cell. On mouseOver should appear `data-original-title` that is tooltip, where is shown a comment. And that comment in tooltip is inside that `attr()`

Comment: @hstur: What kind of tooltip library is showing that? Does it support HTML? Again, we can't help you if you don't tell us what you're working with. Be **generous** with contextual information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would really love to tell you all you need, but I am telling you all I know, I got this part of code for bugfix, it's small part of huge project...
I can just add HTML, where it is used:
`<a class="show-in-modal info-comment info-comment complete" data-toggle="tooltip" id="comment-26725" onclick="return showInModal(this)" style="color:#26A65B" href="/land/comment?idLand=26725" data-original-title="Test user<br />2017/03/21 12:07:11<br />test" title="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, I had to replace `<br />` with `\x0A` and than set in CSS

```
.tooltip {white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing you are using a bootstrap tooltip. in this case add 
`data-html="true"` inside the `a` tag that  has the `data-toggle="tooltip"` atribute

```js
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3>Some text here</h3>

<a class="show-in-modal info-comment info-comment complete" data-toggle="tooltip" id="comment-26725" onclick="return showInModal(this)" style="color:#26A65B" href="/land/comment?idLand=26725" data-original-title="Test user<br />2017/03/21 12:07:11<br />test" title="" data-html="true">Hover over this link</a>
```