# How to execute the html code added into the string passed as a string value to attr tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider two strings:

```
name = "Hello"
mess = "Whats up"
```

Now to a tooltip class, I m trying to add an `attr` tag as follows:

```
$(this.el).find('.checkcalls').attr('title', "#{name}<br/>#{mess}")
```

This prints:

```
"Hello<br/>Whats up"
```

I do not want to print the break tag, rather execute it.

I've tried:

```
  $(this.el).find('.checkcalls').attr('title', '#{name}<br/>#{mess}')
```

and:

```
 $(this.el).find('.checkcalls').attr('title', '"#{name}"<br/>"#{mess}"')
```

They don't print the desired result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you adding <br> tag when adding attribute ?

Comment: Try new line character `\n` instead of `br` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use br - use \n instead:

```
$(this.el).find('.checkcalls').attr('title', '"#{name}"\n"#{mess}"');
```

I don't know backbone, but this should work.

## Edit:

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/358903/), and it's true - it's so simple! Just add an actual, press-the-enter-key linebreak!

```
$(this.el).find('.checkcalls').attr('title', '"#{name}
#{mess}"');
```

Comment: But this prints "#{name}#{mess}"

Comment: So we cannot add any sort of html code in an attribute?