# new line for title JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put every new word for title on the new line using js. I tried different ways, but they don't work.

`dictionary.title += word.value;` - here I add attribute title for my dictionary class with `word.value` value. It comes together like: "HelloI'mJohn" instead of 
"Hello 
I'm 
John".
 How can I do that on the new line using JavaScript code?

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip

Comment: What is `dictonary`? What is `word.value`? **If** you're trying to have a multi-line tooltip by setting the `title` property of a DOM element, having newlines (`\n`) in the string should work. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/0b5cta7f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> \n

or

> br tag

for new line.

```
dictionary.title += word.value + "\n";
```

Comment: But the OP seems to be saying that they already have `\n` (not `/n`!) in the text, so this is already what they're trying to do. (And no, not a `<br>` tag.)

Comment: It adds /n to the text, but doesn't switch to the new line: "Hello/nI'm/nJohn"

Answer (score -1):

Like in the above answers as said you can use `<br>` and `\n` for the new line but there are many alternative ways you can achieve this for your understand I have written a code where I used a 



 tag which is also called a block element where it takes given width and height and add a new line at the end automatically. There are many block-level elements you can also use for new lines.

```js
let value = document.querySelector(".newInput");
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
let div = document.querySelector(".dictionary");


function storeValues(){
let dictionary = "";
if(value.value){
  dictionary += `<p>${value.value}</p>`
}

div.innerHTML += dictionary

}


btn.addEventListener("click", storeValues);
```

```html
Enter Word: <input type='text' class='newInput'/>
 <button type='submit' class='newInput'>Submit</button>
 
 
 <div class='dictionary'>
 <!-- Dicitonary will appear here-->
 </div>
```