# Is is possible to have empty lines in markup link titles?

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown, tooltip

This markup leads to this HTML:

```
[tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com "This is the tooltip text.")
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="This is the tooltip text.">tooltip</a>
```

And would look like this (with a title showing on hover), which is all good and dandy:

[tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com)

---

What I would like is something like this, where there are **empty lines** in the **link title**:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="This is..

indeed... 

... a tooltip text.">tooltip</a>
```

This is possible to do using HTML just fine getting a title that shows the empty lines on hover.

But you can't seem to do this using markdown:

```
[tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com "This is..

indeed... 

... a tooltip text.")
```

Which ends up yielding:

[tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com "This is..

indeed...

... a tooltip text.")

---

So my question is: **Is there a way to have empty lines in link titles using markdown?**

```
I've tried "<br/>" and "\" but they do not work in link titles sadly
```

(alternative suggestions to pure markdown is fine too thank you)

Comment: The thing you're calling a tooltip isn't a tooltip. It's a link. Don't abuse links as tooltips. use `<abbr>` or `<span title="...">` or something closer to the semantics you want.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant have empty lines in link titles using markdown.

```
No
```

Comment: @mb21 says that your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [HTML entity `&#10;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip), this markdown:

```
[tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com "This is&#10;&#10;the&#10;&#10;tooltip text.")
```

[renders to](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%5Btooltip%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%20%22This%20is%26%2310%3B%26%2310%3Bthe%26%2310%3B%26%2310%3Btooltip%20text.%22)):

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="This is

the

tooltip text.">tooltip</a>
```