# New line in title attribute?

Tags: html, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

Currently if I want to insert a new line in `title=`, I would do this:

```
<span id="dummy" title="Hello
World!">Dummy</span>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/XFMfx/

But this looks really weird to me, and it just messes up my HTML file. Just imagine all those `new lines` in it.
So I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, so that it won't mess it up.

Thanks.

Comment: check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. There are **no cross-browser solutions**. If you want a line break in your title attribute, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title).

Comment: @jaychapani: I'm aware of that question, and like I've stated, there are no cross-browser solutions to this.

Answer (score 3):

As of Firefox 12 (which is the current Aurora version), this is (finally) supported. See [the related bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358452).