# Java / Html - Linebreaks work in title but not in alt attribute (IE8)

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer-8

I want to display an image with a title and an alt attribute.
They both display the same content which is stored in a variable.
Before displaying I replace all occurences of "\n" with "
".
Now the interesting part:
When hovering over the image, the title displays the text correctly (sentence under sentence) but the alt text shows "
" instead of breaking the lines.

What the heck is going on? O_o

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
        ...
        tooltipText = tooltipText.replaceAll("\n", "&#10;");
        startElement(HTML.IMG_ELEM, someName);
        writeAttribute(HTML.TITLE_ATTR, tooltipText);
        writeAttribute(HTML.ALT_ATTR, tooltipText);
        ...
```

Comment: where do you replace that using what? code would be usefull

Comment: you shouldn't expect to have full control over the title and alt text. I don't think the lines they contain are meant to be breaked

Answer (score 0):

I googled around and found this other question on Stack Overflow that may help you: [newline in <td title="">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title)

edit - tested on Firefox 14.0.1 (Ubuntu). Can't test with IE8, though.