# How can I add new line/linebreak character in title attribute in HTML

Tags: html, css, hover, accessibility

I am using this

`<a href="#" title="select from 1: this 2: that" > Click here </a>`

When someone hover over it I see all the text in one line.

Is there any way to show it on new line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/246451/2261259

Answer (score 123):

You can use `&#013;` or `&#010;`.

```html
<a href="#" title="select from 1: this &#013; 2: that" >Click here</a>

<a href="#" title="select from 1: this &#010; 2: that" >Click here</a>
```

Comment: not working in `Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)` in fedora (linux)

Comment: Both `&#013;` and `&#010;` work for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: If they do not work individually for your browser, try using both together, and that should do the trick, `&#10;&#13;`.

Comment: that prefix `0` looks like octal, but they're not?

Comment: If you're setting the attribute through JavaScript you need to include an actual newline literal using backticks with a newline between them (\n did not work for me). The HTML entity codes in this answer only work in HTML (which makes sense of course).

Answer (score 27):

If you are generating it dynamically put < br/> in html part and \n in non html part

```js
$("td").attr("title", "One \n Two \n Three");
$("td").html("One <br/> Two \n <br/>Three <br/>");
$("td").append("One \n Two \n Three");
$("td").append("<br/>One <br/> Two \n Three");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

This is using Jquery framework.

Answer (score 15):

```html
<a href="#" title="select from 
1: this 
2: that" >Click here</a>
```

Comment: but what about if i am dynamically generating that from database. what character i need to put

Comment: @user26 You need to put a new line. For example, in PHP, you would do: `echo '<a title="one\ntwo">';`. Remember to use proper escaping using `htmlspecialchars` if you are printing something from the database.

Comment: If you want a newline but don't want to mess up your HTML, use `&#13;`.

Answer (score 12):

As you tagged this with accessibility, I would say the most robust approach is not to rely on the title for information.

The [current HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-title-attribute) discourages this use as people using who cannot use a mouse (e.g. due to mobility impairment) but use a keyboard and see the screen will never see your tooltip/title text. People using touch screens cannot access it.

Most people using a screen reader will not be aware of the title text either, although it is possible to access in most screen readers it is not read out by default, and someone would have to know to look for it. (And [there are more issues](http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/wacblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?id=38).)

The spec suggests using this for line breaks:

> If the title attribute's value contains "LF" (U+000A) characters, the content is split into multiple lines. Each "LF" (U+000A) character represents a line break.

However, the display of the new lines is dependant on the browser ([How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)).

I suspect that the overall UI approach needs a little more thought, as many people would be confused by the sort of instruction in your example, i.e. what does clicking on it achieve if there are multiple options?

If your situation makes it difficult to [write good link text](http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/writing-good-link-text/) then I would post up more about the interaction at the [UX stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).