# Customize the html tooltip text

Tags: html, css

```html
<abbr title="This is an example. This is an example. ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExample">test<abbr>
```

How I want it to be viewed:

```
This is an example. This is an example.
ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample
ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExample
```

How is it actually viewed:

```
This is an example. This is an example. ThisIsAnExam
pleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample Th
isIsAnExample
```

How can I customize this behaviour? How to select the `title` using css?

Comment: Not possible. You should create a div, and using javascript that div will have the contents of your title, and will only show on hover. You can try to consider using Bootstrap, or check how they did it.

Comment: I am sure it is possible because here on stackoverflow when I run the snippet, it is giving me the desired view but not on my website with the same browser.

Comment: You were asking on **How to select the title using css**, so it is not possible. You can check @Roy 's link

Comment: @threeFatCat Any official documentation link that you can post here?

Comment: @Roy Did you inspect the title of stackoverflow? It does not have any break tag, while the answers in the particular dupe(you think) you posted suggests using a break tag.

Comment: **What aren't you guys getting my point?** It works on stackoverflow, not on my website. Using the same browser.

Comment: How about using tooltip? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 1):

> Try using `<b>&#013;</b>` which is used for `<br>` line break:

```html
<abbr title="This is an example. This is an example. &#013; ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample &#013; ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExample">test<abbr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: *Hope it helps.*, no it doesn't.

Comment: Add usefull comment instead of typing it doesn't comment why it doesn't.

Comment: I don't have any control over the title, I can not customize it. I don't want to customize it using JS. I am interested in just CSS selector.

Comment: And btw, you missed the `;` after `&#013`

Comment: @roundAbout I don't know but for me it worked (at least in Chrome Version 76). By the way this is possibly a dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606877/how-can-i-new-newline-in-title-attribute-in-html/18612227

Comment: @marcramser That's the problem. It works on stackoverflow, not on my website. I am sure there is something that I am missing. Btw, I have seen that answer and it is not a duplicate, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, use `&#10;`

```html
<abbr title="This is an example. This is an example.&#10;
ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample &#10;
ThisIsAnExampleThisIsAnExample ThisIsAnExample">test<abbr>
```