# (HTML) How can i use the \n in title attribute?

Tags: html

I would like to have something like `<a href="#" title="email\nphone"></a>` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561351/8304027

Comment: yes this is perfect. thank you !

Answer (score -2):

You have to put the text inside a

> `<a href="#" title="email\nphone">text here</a>`