# Is there a way to add a new line to display in the title attribute of an Anchor tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I am using this code to store HTML code in a variable called `$conversions`

```
$conversions = "GBP " . number_format($file*0.84) . "CHF " . number_format($file*1.23)
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to add a `<br>` before the word "CHF ".

Any ideas?

The whole code is as follows:

```
<?php
$file = get_field('fl_price');
if(trim($file) == ""){echo 'Price on Application' ;}else{$conversions = "GBP " . number_format($file*0.84) . "<br />CHF " . number_format($file*1.23)  ;echo 'EUR ' . number_format($file) . "</br><a class=\"wp-tooltip\" title=\" $conversions \">Other Currencies</a>" ;}
?>
```

Comment: Where's the line of PHP that `echo`s the contents of `$conversions`? Also, why can't you just change `"CHF "` to `"<br />CHF "`? Also, try reading about [what makes a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Help us to help you.

Comment: Have you tried adding it in the quotes?

Comment: i have posted the full code.. your answer doesn't work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [newline in <td title="">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title)

Comment: You want a carriage return (`&#013;`) or a line feed (`&#010;`), not a `<br>`.  Seeing many outdated/wrong answer.  Better thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title

Answer (score 1):

```
$conversions = "GBP " . number_format($file*0.84) . "&#xA;CHF " . number_format($file*1.23);
```

Echoing `$conversions` will now have a HTML-linebreak before CHF.

Comment: html is output like this <div class="ccvalue">
EUR 1,000,000</br><a class="wp-tooltip" title=" GBP 840,000<br />CHF 1,230,000 &#8220;>Other Currencies</a></div>

Comment: The output is not normal HTML, but the content of a title-attribute. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title (in other words, replace `<br />` with `&#xA;`)

Comment: I made a fiddle in my answer. It definitely works for me in Chrome, but that's the only place I've tested.  Possibly a browser issue, or you're introducing a typo of some sort in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your string to an attribute of `<a>` called `title`.  This isn't going to be displayed and is certainly not going to render any HTML (like a br tag).

edit:

As per OptimusCrime's suggestion, this does work:
http://jsfiddle.net/5rM4u/1/

Replace your `<br/>` with `&#xA;` and you're good to go.

Comment: this works actually without the "<br />".. the problem is adding a breaking line

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect what you're actually asking. This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. You're simply trying to add a line break to the `title` element of an `Anchor` tag. OptimusCrime's suggestion appears correct.

Comment: Using Firefox - HTML Output is this but it doesn't give a new line:  <div class="ccvalue">
EUR 1,000,000</br><a class="wp-tooltip" title=" GBP 840,000&#xA;CHF 1,230,000 ">Other Currencies</a></div>

Comment: Works in FF 24.0. http://jsfiddle.net/5rM4u/2/ (and Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE10)

Comment: ok the problem actually lies with the way this plugin renders the tooltip - I can momentarily see the breaking line before the document fully loads but when wp-tooltip kicks in the breaking line is removed.. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-tooltip/

Comment: i don't suppose anyone here is so heisenberg to go into the plugin and sort this out :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the $conversions variable in the "title" of the "a" tag. just using `<br />` will not work.

See some of the answers to this question "[How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)" it may contain the answer that you are looking for.