# jquery - newline in title tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

This is my working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/gvot4n1e/1/

Basically, I want to show a tooltip when the mouse goes over a certain place - thats working, but what is not working is that I cannot get it to split into multiple lines (it only displays on one line)

I have even tried (after searching) using the solution from here:
[newline in <td title="">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title)

but it does not work :(

If you don't want to visit the working code at jsfiddle on top, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Tooltip only Text
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');


         //title = str.replace("PPPPP", "\n");


        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('1200');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 15; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + -30; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add style `white-space: pre-line;` to the tooltip class

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s2dthLs5/

Comment: Ah! It's a CSS problem while I was searching for a JQuery problem :) Thanks!