# newline in title of element html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a list of users in title & each user has a line, I try this :

```
var favTitle;

for(var j=0;j<like_favs[1].length;j++)
    favTitle +=like_favs[1][j].username+"\n";

$("#Item").append('<i title="In favorite users : '+favTitle+'">Favorite</i>');
```

I've also tried `"&#13;"` and `"&#10;"`
but it does not work everything is written in one line, please help by anyway to leave a line.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a line break (`<br>`) at the end of each line.

```
$("#fav").append('<i title="In favorite users : '+favTitle+'">Item</i><br>');
```

Comment: This leaves a new line for each element `<i>`
 But I want to display the `<i>` element one time  and the attr `title `contains a lines

Comment: HTML attributes are not meant to be visually formatted. There's a way explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246438/newline-in-td-title

It might not display reliably in different browsers. You're better off building a tooltip that you can actually format with HTML and css.

Answer (score 0):

`&#13;` should work (I've tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge):

```js
let users = [{username: 'user1'}, {username: 'user2'}, {username: 'user3'}];
let favTitle = '';
for(let j = 0; j < users.length; j++)
    favTitle += users[j].username + "&#13;";

$("#item").append('<i title="In favorite users: &#13;' + favTitle + '">Favorite</i>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = item></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, otherwise, you should **update** your browser:

```
var favTitle = '';
for(var j=0;j<like_favs[1].length;j++)
    favTitle +=like_favs[1][j].username+"&#13;";

$("#Item").append('<i title="In favorite users : &#13;'+favTitle+'">Favorite</i>');
```

Comment: @Nourein what browser are you using ? and which version ?